# Separate Model for storing Choices vs Choices Field in a Model Django

Tags: python, django, model

Currently, I implemented the status as a separate model like this

```
class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Order(models.Model):
        status = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

but I just realized that Django has a field called "choices". Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#choices

based on that Django docs, I think my model should be like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    UNPAID = 'UNPAID'
    PAID = 'PAID'
    ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (UNPAID, 'UNPAID'),
        (PAID, 'PAID'),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=UNPAID,
    )
```

By using this, I think I don't need a separate model called "OrderStatus" anymore.

Here are my questions.

1. Is there any downside if I keep my implementation?
2. If I change/refactor my code to use the "choices" field. Can I add more status in the future? do I only have to add more items in the ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES variable? Are there other things that I have to do?

Comment: Just a quick note that in the 2nd approach, you have to make a new migration every time you add a new choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add as much choise as possible you want.
You can use django enum to make happens

Here you go how you can use it:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types

Whever you add new choise item in your `enum` class, make sure you have make migrations commands

Comment: is there any downside if i keep my current implementation?

Comment: No downside, but if you do my suggested way, you can things done more easily and efficently